# how to get specific parameters value from 2-3 days old builds of jenkins using groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-scriptler

I want to retrieve old build number, version number and some other variables from build of some **maven project**. That build happened 2-3 days before. I tried following groovy script to retrieve variables.

```
import hudson.model.*

for(item in Hudson.instance.items) 
{
  prop = item.getAllJobs()
  for(param in prop) 
  {
        build = param.getLastSuccessfulBuild()
        println(build)
        println("------------------------------------------")
        variabls = build.getBuildVariables()
        for(vb in variabls) 
        {
            println (vb)
        }
                println("------------------------------------------")
        env = build.getWorkspace()
        for(ev in env) 
        {
            println (ev)
        }   
  }
 }
```

I was successful in retrieving build number, but I also want version number for project for which build was done. I also tried APIs on Build from jenkins JAVADOC, but somehow failed to get answer.
Is their any way to get that?

I might think of getting this version number by reading POM from workspace of previous build, but all want to know is their any other way by which I can get that version number of maven build.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Either you can read from pom.xml or you can read from the build log as well.

Maven adds this line in the build, (using regex)

> Building Project/Module Version